# CORDOVA BUILDING APP WARNING ABOUT ANDROIDX

Tags: cordova

**Im trying to build the cordova app in terminal and this one shows up.**

[Gradle Properties] Detected Gradle property "android.useAndroidX" with the value of "true", Cordova's recommended value is "false"

[Gradle Properties] Detected Gradle property "android.enableJetifier" with the value of "true", Cordova's recommended value is "false"

Comment: try this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter and build again

Comment: is your build failing or are you just concerned about the warning?  In my project, I have AndroidX enabled and I get that warning too.  The build does complete and the app seems to run just fine.

I'm building with Android@7.0.1 and am targeting as follows:
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />

@AmitSoni, for my project the plugin doesn't address the warning.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have to preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="false" in config.xml.

when built gradle.properties by cordova,
cordova use the value of AndroidXEnabled in config.xml.

As the result of upper guide, below values are set in gradle.properties file.

android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false

this is guide for ionic cordova platform add android.